# GET Request in Flutter

Tags: json, rest, api, flutter, request

i start yesteraday with flutter and today i have a problem with GET request.

**It looks like I can't get data from my URL, I have no idea why when I paste it into my browser everything works**

I tried to get one single `User` object, but nothing work for me :(

my code,

User.dart

```
class User{
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;

  User(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    email = json['email'];
  }
}
```

my GET function:

```
Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/current';
    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

my widget:

```
class UserPageState extends State<UserPage>{
  Future<List<dynamic>> _user;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCurrentUser(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData ){
                return Container(
                  child: Center(child: Text(snapshot.data['firstName']),),
                );
              }else {
                return Text('NOT LOAD');
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when i paste my `url` into browser it show me:

```
{
createdAt: 1584905291338,
updatedAt: 1584905291338,
id: 3,
firstName: "name",
lastName: "surname",
email: "surname@name.com",
admin: false
}
```

I don't have any more idea what i can do it, 
PLEASE HELP ME :(

Comment: Probably you need to pass something to the server to get the data? (Token or id or something like that in the header)

Comment: @MidhunMP but when i run in the browser this link all is ok and return me correctly data

Comment: There needs to be some way to identify which user details need to be returned right ? You have to pass some-kind of parameter to server to identify which user data you need to get, correct ? Try removing those header field from the code and check

Comment: I removing and without changes, i don't have to provide any parameter to server when i run this url

Comment: It may be that your server doesn't like that dart will lower case the work accept in the header. BTW, how are you setting that header in the browser? Have you tried your request from Postman?

Comment: @RichardHeap, yes, i try in postman, is this same like in a browser, i don't change anything

Comment: Since you are using http, can you obtain a packet capture on the server (10.0.2.2) of a good and bad request?

Comment: Yes, i use ```10.0.2.2``` in different controller in this app and all works great, i don't hve idea why here not work

Comment: I do not have to set the header by performing a request

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend, that you fetch your data from the `initState` in the StatefulWidget, and not within the build method. Otherwise, on every rebuild, the data is fetched newly via http.get. In your `FutureBuilder` widget you use then `future: _user`

```dart
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UserPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  UserPageState createState() => UserPageState();
}

class UserPageState extends State<UserPage>{
  Future<User> _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ... // your code here
```

To answer your question and why the user class and its data isn't filled. You have to return the data from the function `User.fromJson(...)`, otherwise it gets lost

```dart
class User{
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;

  User(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return User(
      json['id'],
      json['firstName'],
      json['lastName'],
      json['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still throw me exception from ```get``` method :(

Comment: Can you post the exact error message, maybe you can print out the statuscode of the response

Comment: status code is 400 :/ error throw me in my ```if``` statement, in ```else throw exception```

Comment: it looks like I can't get data from my URL, I have no idea why when I paste it into my browser everything works

Comment: Just to make sure: Please try this URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3 and tell me if you still get the exception and 400 status code

Comment: right now i have 200, something idea why i cant use data from my url?

Comment: when i run in the browser this link all is ok and return me correctly data

Comment: I think you have a restriction from your phone / emulator to your local webserver. Is the server on the same machine, then you can try localhost instead of the IP.

Comment: Try to print what exception you got

Answer (score 0):

```
class User{
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;

  // For me, it's better to use named parameter to make it easier to read
  User({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email});

  // this doesn't return User object
  User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    email = json['email'];
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      firstName : json['firstName '],
      lastName : json['lastName '],
      email : json['email '],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still throw me exception from ```get``` method :(